# How do I fix this parse error in my php file ?

Tags: php, parse-error

I'm getting the follow error in the code below: (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`' in).

```
<?php
    include_once 'connect.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';

    sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
        if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Login success 
            header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    `   //echo 'Login Successful';
        } 
        else {
            // Login failed 
            header('Location: ../loginpage.php?error=1');
        //echo "Login Unsuccessful";
        }
    } 
    else {
        // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
        echo "Invalid Request";
    } ?>
```

Comment: Is this the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

You missing closing curly brace for

```
if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
```

also missing closing curly brace for parent if condition

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'connect.php' or 'functions.php' file will be include '`' character. 
Please investigate these files.